# Split single table to many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin, many-to-many, database-normalization

I have a table that looks like the following:

[image]

I want to split this to 3 different tables with a PK-FK relationship. Essentially a province can have many state, a state can have many cities. What is the best way to do this in one shot using a SQL query if it's even possible? Or using tools like phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Province table:

```
Province_ID (PK)
Province_Name
```

State table:

```
State_ID (PK)
State_Name
Province_ID (FK)
AreaCode
```

Citi table:

```
Citi_ID (PK)
Citi_Name
State_ID (FK)
Citi_Code
```

I don't think there's any tools that can help you normalize this table automatically. So you have to create these tables by code then using sql query to insert values into it

Comment: Can you at least give me an example, once I have the tables set up on the query to populate the content?

Comment: Getting the province table set up is pretty much easy. But not sure about the 2nd table.

Comment: The table structure is just like i described in my answer. About the query, you can reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285551/inserting-values-from-one-table-into-another-table

Answer (score 0):

You may Partition It as follow :

`Prov Table with Prov_ID as PK.`

`State Table with State_ID as PK and Prov_ID as FK`

`City Table with City_ID as PK and State_ID as FK and Prov_ID as FK`